# Verify Result of a Calculation

Tags: proof-verification, transformation

In the journal: ["A Closed Form Solution for the Similarity Transformation Parameters of Two Planar Point Sets"](http://eprints2.utem.edu.my/10042/1/jmet.vol5.no1.fullpaper6.pdf), I cannot get same value for scaling factor for the same problem in the journal. Here is the problem :

Suppose

[image: Vi]

[image: Ui]

[image]

[image: Tetha]

Scaling factor (c) can be found using equation (23) in the journal :

[image: Eq 23]

Where :

[image: Some Condition]

In the Journal value for c is 0.7211, but I cannot get the same value.
My value for c is -0.6102, and for other variable : E1 = -4.160 , E2 = -2.126, E3 = 5.0 , E4 = 1.667.

I want to ask you to verify value for scaling factor (c) and for E1, E2,E3 and E4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a typo in equation E1 and E2, the correct one is :

[image: corrected typo]